# What is the difference between "violkolora" and "purpura"?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, colors

The translation for purple is **violkolora**. However, the word **purpura** also exists. Does it refer to the same color, or is it more similar to the French "pourpre", which is more red?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are definitely not the same, PIV defines *purpura* like this:

> Havanta la koloron de la purpuro

PIV defines *purpuro* like this:

> *purpur/o:
>
> - 1 **Violruĝa kolorilo**, kiun la antikvuloj eltiris el konkoj de mureksoj k de parenca sp.: la Tira purpuro estis la plej ŝatata.
> - 2 Ŝtofo, tinkturita per tiu kolorilo, k rigardata de la antikvuloj kiel apartaĵo de reĝoj, konsuloj ks, de la modernuloj kiel apartaĵo de la kardinaloj: delikata tolo k purpuro estas ŝiaj vestojX; naskita en la purpuro (de la reĝa familio); kiuj estis edukitaj sur purpuro, tiuj ruliĝas nun sur sterkoX; levi iun al la purpuro (kardinaligi).
> - 3 ⚕ Purpurao.

The first definition is the one of the french *pourpre*, here is the definition from the Larousse:

> Dérivé bromé de l'indigo, extrait du gastropode Murex brandaris, et qui servait dans l'Antiquité à teindre les tissus en rouge.

This is how *pourpre* (French) (*purpura*) looks like according to Google:
[image]

This is how *purple* (English) (*violkolora*) looks like according to Google:
[image]

Answer (score 8):

[Reta Vortaro](http://www.reta-vortaro.de/revo/) has these definitions:

> **Violkoloro:** Koloro de violo, meza inter bluo kaj ruĝo.

Translation:

> **Violkoloro:** The color of a violet, midway between blue and red

and

> **Purpuro:** Violruĝa koloro

Translation:

> **Purpuro:** Violet-red color

So from that I gather that "purpuro" is more reddish, so if you see something that is a reddish purple, you'd say "tio estas purpura", and if you see something of a more bluish purple, you'd say "tio estas violkolora", and it appears that "violkolora" is not incorrect in either case.

Answer (score 1):

There are few things worth remembering.

1. The basic word in Esperanto is *viola* (*violkolora*). So if the precise distinction isn't important, *viola* is the way to go.
2. In physics *viola* would refer to the colour of the light on the visible spectrum, as opposed to *purpura*, which is a mix between the violet light and red light.
3. For a quick distinction between the two I recommend this comparison: [image: Viola kaj purpura koloroj.]