# What is "jewelry" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

ReVo contains:

- jewel - juvelo
- jewelry box - juvelujo
- jewelry shop - juvelejo

There are no hits for "jewelry" alone, and since the two last words are built from the root for *jewel*, I still have no idea what to say.

Answer (score 7):

In English, *jewel* usually means a precious stone. It is sometimes used for the item of clothing incorporating it, but it is more common to say *a piece of jewellery* or *an item of jewellery*, etc.

The *Universala Vortaro* defines *juvel'* as the stone, which would make *juvelaĵo* the piece. However, in his translation of the Old Testament, Zamenhof has (Dan. 11:38):

> *per oro, arĝento, multekostaj ŝtonoj, kaj juveloj* — with gold, silver, costly stones and treasures

which seems to make a fairly clear distinction.

The word *gemo* (gemstone) was made official in 1919 (though the *Dua Oficiala Aldono* was drawn up in 1914), and PIV defines *juvelo* as a piece of jewellery, so that, for example, a person who only works with precious metals can still be called a *juvelisto*.

Therefore, I would say that nowadays ***juvelo*** means "piece of jewellery", ***juvelaĵo*** means "(some) jewellery", and ***juvel(aĵ)aro*** means "jewellery collection."

- *Ŝi decidis surmeti juvelojn.* She decided to put on some jewellery.
- *En la skatolo kuŝis ormoneroj kaj juvelaĵo.* In the box lay gold coins and jewellery.

Answer (score 2):

JC Wells' *Esperanto Dictionary* gives ***juveloj*** and ***juvelaĵaro***

Answer (score 2):

There are a few important things to consider before trying to translate the meaning of "jewelry".Firstly, the idea of "jewelry" in English isn't, at least anymore, tied to jewels. Secondly, the meanings of words in Esperanto don't always neatly line up with their etymological anticedants, which often causes confusion (like [here](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/615/what-is-the-difference-between-violkolora-and-purpura) and [here](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/what-is-the-difference-between-torto-and-kuko)).

*Juvelo* doesn't necessarily mean "jewel" like in English anymore, even if it may have at an earlier time; that designation goes more to *gemo*. If by *juvelo*, you mean something made out of jewels to wear, that is appropriate, but that is only because, according to the PIV, it's defined as:

> Ornamaĵo, ordinare malgranda, tre multekosta pro la materio (oro,
> arĝento, gemoj) aŭ la prilaboriteco.
>
> An ornamentation, ordinarily small, very costly because of the
> material (gold, silver, gems) or the fashioning.

Which brings on the fact that not everything we call "jewelry" meets all or most of those qualifiers, being very cheap or made of cheap materials like plastic or wood or shells. One could still call them *juvelo*, but a better fit may simply be *ornamaĵo* or *persona ornamaĵo* to be more precise. This isn't to say that *juvelo* can't be used for that purpose or that new terminology should be phased in, simply that *persona onamaĵo* remains an option for precision.

This would make a paradigm something like:

gemo: gem, jewel

juvelo: a piece of jewelry (especially of jewels or gems)

(persona) ornamaĵo: (personal) ornament, a piece of jewellery of any material.

Comment: Good point about the materials!